# VB6 Randomize function?

Tags: random, vb6, legacy-code

I'm working on some (*messy*) legacy code, and I came across this snippet in `Form_Load`:

```
[other code]

Dim r As Byte
Dim g As Byte
Dim b As Byte
Randomize

[more code]
```

I'm still relatively new to many parts of VB, so please excuse my ignorance if it's blatant and smacking you in the face, but can anyone tell me what's going on here? I'm fine with the variable declarations, those make sense. But what is "Randomize" just doing hanging out there? Is this supposed to be VB's randomize function? If so, it's not actually *doing* anything here, is it? I initially thought it was calling a function/sub that the original designer(s) wrote, but nothing like that exists. There are no errors in the program (though there are hundreds of useless lines) and if I comment "Randomize" out, nothing seems to change at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Randomize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266225%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) seeds the random number generator with the current system time (corresponds to `srand(time(NULL))` if you're used to C or C++). Like in any other language, the random generator should normally only be seeded once (at application startup), but a common mistake is to seed it inside some method that is called repeatedly, so I wouldn't be surprised if that is the case here.

Note, though, that without any call to `Randomize`, the *same* sequence of random numbers will be generated each time the program starts.

Comment: Note that there are exceptions, sometimes it is good to seed the random number generator more than once in a program.

Comment: @WTP: True, but then you'd normally supply the seed yourself in order to achieve some particular effect. Reseeding with the system time is almost pointless.

Comment: This makes complete sense, thank you. I think due to the various developers working on this, it got moved away from where it would make any sort of spatial sense within the code, but I see where it's used later on. Much appreciated.

Comment: @erekalper: "Moved away from where it would make any sort of spatial sense" - excellent formulation of a very familiar phenomenom ;-)

Comment: @Aasmund: Trying to be delicate/civil brings out the "best" in the language used to describe problems. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Randomize seeds the random number generator.  If the function "Rnd" (which generates a random number) appears elsewhere in the code, Randomize is very likely not useless.

Answer (score 1):

`Randomize [optional seed]` *seeds* the random number generator for all subsequent calls to `Rnd`.